# Insert algebraic expressions in mysql table

Tags: mysql, insert

i have data like this 5x^2 + 3y^2. and i want to add this in my database what are the possible solutions to do this. and what actually i have to use for symbols like [] () {} and integration or derivative sign.

Any help!! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to insert the equation as string?

Comment: and do you have any problem inserting those expressions on the database?

Comment: @JohnroePauloCañamaque No. actually i have image files with some algebraic expressions. I want to add as it is my database not by giving path of the image.

Comment: @JohnWoo Yes when i write this query it breaks my mysql insert operation.

Comment: what is the data type of the column? I can reproduce it without having any error. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9778e/1

Comment: @JohnWoo well i got it but how we insert integration symbol in this? is there anything that would allow me to put whole expression as it looks like on paper? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
INSERT INTO table_name(c1,c2) VALUES ('5x^2 + 3y^2','{5x+y}');
```

**Result:**

[image]

Are you looking for this..

Comment: Yes Exactly!! Thank You

One Thing More how can i insert symbols like Pi, Derivatives and integration.

Comment: @ammarali29 to insert symbol please refer http://usefulshortcuts.com/alt-codes/maths-alt-codes.php